# CCFollow with CCParticleSystem

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to follow some sprite by some instance of CCParticleSystem using CCFollow. I don't want to make instance of CCParticleSystem a child of sprite, because I want it to be displayed some time after sprite removed.
When moving sprite from bottom-left to top-right corner my ParticleSystem moves from center to bottom-left corner. I can't understand why does it happen.

Here is sample code:

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) ) {
        CCSprite *someSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
        [self addChild:someSprite];
        id action = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:5 position:ccp(480,320)];
        [someSprite runAction:action];

        CCParticleSystemQuad *effect = [CCParticleMeteor node];
//      effect.positionType = kCCPositionTypeFree;
//      effect.positionType = kCCPositionTypeRelative;
//      effect.positionType = kCCPositionTypeGrouped; changing of positionType to any of this options does not make any sense
        [effect runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:someSprite]];
        [self addChild:effect];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a case of bad documentation.

I tried this myself and got the same result. By looking at the code and the fragment of documentation that exists, the CCFollow action is intended to be used only on fullscreen nodes like CCLayer, CCScene and perhaps CCNode. I would document it as follows:

> CCFollow is an action for scrolling the entire screen by allowing the
>   layer or scene follow another node, such as a player object. It's an
>   alternative for moving the Camera object or updating the position
>   manually.